# How to express sin(180/n) in terms of sin(1/n)

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried many ways such as trying to complete and make formulas of  $\sin p + \sin q$ and many more things but every time I am getting and absurd result so how to accurately do it?

How to express $\sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)$ as $\sin\left(\frac 1n\right)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: There is a sequence of polynomials $U_k(y)$ called the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind which have the property: $$U_{k-1}(\cos x)\sin(x)=\sin(kx).$$ You can use $\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ to then write $\sin(kx)$ in terms of $\sin x.$ Here you want $k=180, x=1/n.$ However, this formula is going to be a big mess, with 150 terms.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use that $\sin(3x)=U(\sin x)$  where $U(y)=3y-4y^3$. Then $\sin(9x)=U(U(\sin x))$ and $\sin(81x)=U(U(\sin(9x))$ then get $\sin(90x)=\sin(81x+9x)$ and finally $\sin(180x)=\sin(2\cdot 90x).$ But you'll need more square roots with this formula.

Comment: $\sin(nx) = \operatorname{im}[(\cos x + i \sin x)^n]$

Answer (score 1):

From the factorization of $180 =2^2\times 3^2\times 5$ repeated use of the
decimation formulas
$$
\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)
$$
$$
\cos(2x)=2\cos^2x -1
$$
$$
\sin(3x)=3\sin x-4\sin^3x
$$
$$
\cos(3x)=4\cos^3x-3\cos x
$$
$$
\sin(5x)=5\sin x-20\sin^3x +16\sin^5 x
$$
$$
\cos(5x)=16\cos^5 x-20\cos^3x +5\cos x
$$
and $\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$ would probably do it.